# Ruby grammar question

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm new to ruby. So I'm confused by the  following lines of code:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :products
  end

end
```

one of the lines makes me most confused is :

```
t.string :title
```

I just can't understand it. So could any of you give me some hint on which part of ruby grammar I need to read in order to understand this single line of code? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just normal Ruby messaging syntax.

```
t.string :title
```

means

1. dereference the block local variable `t`
2. send the message `:string` to the object referenced by `t` and pass the literal symbol `:title` as the only argument

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit here, but as a basis for exploration

:title is a Ruby "symbol" - basically a hack to provide higher-efficiency string-like constants - so t.string :title is a bit like calling a `t.string("title")` in more popular OO languages, and given you seem to be declaring a record structure for the database, I'd say that's adding a field effectively "called" title with type "string".

Comment: what does () as method calling have to do with object orientation?

Comment: `:something` is a symbol, not an immutable string and therefore not equivalent to `"something"`. A symbol is actually an index on the global symbol table, and much more efficient in comparisons and hash key lookups.

Comment: @edgerunner: I'd forgotten the Ruby-specific terminology - been a couple years since I've done any Ruby, but at a general computing science / object level I think it's fair to say it's an immutable string, and your reply seems to confirm that, no?

Comment: @Matt Briggs: `()` alone has nothing to do with OO, but the general syntax `object.member-function()` does... procedural languages like C don't use that notation.

Comment: @Tony, to the best of my knowledge, that string is hashed and the resulting integer is stored in the table

Comment: @edgerunner: ok, I'll try to update my answer accordingly... thanks!

Comment: A symbol isn't a hack - it's a constraint - and constraints are liberating!

Comment: @Matt: I think he's saying that other languages (which happen to be OO) require brackets, even though ruby doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer within [Why's poignant guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-1.html)

P.S. It's spelt grammar, but for code we'd usually use the word 'syntax'. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this out this might prove to be very helpful](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-migrations.htm)
This file is called [migration file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) it creates the backend for your app
[Another link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)

Answer (score 0):

to fully understand that file, you need to understand classes, inheritance, modules, method calling, blocks and symbols.